# 【Idioms】 get something over with = get something over and done with

Tags: idioms

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ko/%EC%82%AC%EC%A0%84/%EC%98%81%EC%96%B4/get-something-over-with

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+(something)+over+and+done+with

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20%28something%29%20over%20with

I have searched for the above idioms.
So I am curious whether both are same.

.

*By Free Dictionary*

*get something over and done with

-To finish something, typically something unpleasant.

e.g.)

```
The doctor told me that I have to get a shot, so let's get it over and done with.
I just want to get this ordeal over and done with!
```

.

*By Cambridge's and Merriam's dictionaries*

*get something over with

-to finish or reach the end of some unpleasant work, experience, or duty:

-to do or finish an unpleasant but necessary piece of work or duty so that you do not have to worry about it in the future:

-to cause or experience the end of (something) : to finish (something)

e.g.)

```
I’ll be glad to get these exams over with

I just want to get this ordeal over with!
```

Comment: Yes, I take them to mean the exact same thing.  I think of it as slightly more emphatic to use the phrase with both. I never hear it without "over", though - No one says "get this thing done with".

Comment: @JustinStafford Wow Okay.. Honestly I have been so curious about them... Haha Thank~~~~ you~~~~ Justin!

Comment: Maybe I should also say that I *do* hear "get this thing done" or "get this done", or "get it done".  Also there is the slightly humorous "get *her* done", normally pronounced quickly and all run together so that "get her" rhymes with "bitter".  Also, I'll point out that I think the grammar of ending with "with" is strange, but for some reason it has become pretty standard.